# How to find all foreign key constraints that are broken in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

We recently discovered an issue with our database where a foreign key constraint was not working correctly. Basically the primary table did not have any primary ids that matched the foreign key in the child table. When we dropped the foreign key constraint and tried to recreate it, it then threw an error that the foreign key constraint could not be created because there were foreign keys with no matching id in the parent table. Once those were cleaned up, it allowed us to recreate the foreign key.

Of course we are wondering how this happened to begin with. I worked with Oracle for 15 years and never saw a foreign key failing in this way. But our concern right now is how many other foreign keys are not working correctly. This is a problem because we have some BEFORE DELETE triggers that fail silently when the calling function returns a null because of a foreign_key_violation (this is how we discovered the issue to begin with).

```
EXCEPTION
    WHEN foreign_key_violation
        THEN RETURN NULL;
```

What we want to do is get all of the foreign keys in the database (probably a few thousand), loop over them all, and check every single one against it's parent table to see if any are "broken".

Basically:

Select all foreign keys using Postgres system tables.

Loop over all of them and do something like:

```
select count(parent_id) from child_table
    where foreign_key_id not in (
        select parent_id as foreign_key_id
        from parent_table
    )
    );
```

For all the ones that are not 0, drop the foreign key constraint, fix the orphaned data, and recreate the foreign key constraint.

Does this sound reasonable? Has anyone done something like this before? What is the best way to get the foreign key constraints from Postgres?

Edit:
What we realized is that if we dropped and recreated the foreign keys, it would tell us which ones were problematic.

```
SELECT 'Alter table ' || conrelid::regclass || ' drop constraint ' || conname || '; alter table ' || conrelid::regclass || ' add constraint ' ||  conname || ' ' || pg_get_constraintdef(oid) || ';'
FROM   pg_constraint
WHERE  contype = 'f'
  AND    connamespace = 'public'::regnamespace
ORDER  BY conrelid::regclass::text, contype DESC;
```

Next, run all the commands. If there are any foreign key violations, they will show up when the alter table add constraint command tries to run. Make a note of which ones had a problem and keep running the following commands until you have a list of all issues.

The following is example of sql commands to fix the issues.

```
delete from child_table where id_child_table in (
    select id_child_table from child_table
    where id_parent_id not in (
        select id_parent_id
        from parent_table
    )
    );

alter table child_table drop constraint child_table_fk1;
alter table child_table add constraint child_table_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (id_parent_table) REFERENCES parent_table(id_parent_table) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE DEFERRABLE;
```

Comment: As to "Of course we are wondering how this happened to begin with.". From [ALTER TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) *DISABLE/ENABLE [ REPLICA | ALWAYS ] TRIGGER*: *Disabling or enabling internally generated constraint triggers requires superuser privileges; it should be done with caution since of course the integrity of the constraint cannot be guaranteed if the triggers are not executed.* Where internal triggers include FK's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a basic data sample :

```
create table test1 (id1 serial, seq1 int, constraint pk1 primary key (id1, seq1));
create table test2 (id2 int, seq2 int, descr2 text, constraint pk2 primary key (id2, seq2), constraint fk1 foreign key (id2, seq2) references test1 (id1, seq1) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT) ;

insert into test1 (seq1) values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);
insert into test2 (id2, seq2, descr2) values (1,1,'A'), (2,2,'B'), (3,3,'C'), (4,4,'D'), (5,5,'E');
```

Considering the query to get the list of foreign keys (source [internet](https://soft-builder.com/how-to-list-all-foreign-keys-in-postgresql-database/)) :

```
SELECT conrelid::regclass AS table_name, 
       conname AS foreign_key, 
       pg_get_constraintdef(oid) 
FROM   pg_constraint 
WHERE  contype = 'f' 
AND    connamespace = 'public'::regnamespace   
ORDER  BY conrelid::regclass::text, contype DESC;
```

Result :

| table_name | foreign_key | pg_get_constraintdef |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test2 | fk1 | FOREIGN KEY (id2, seq2) REFERENCES test1(id1, seq1) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT |

With some changes to get a computable resulting list :

```
SELECT conrelid::regclass AS ReferencingTable
     , a.ReferencingKey
     , b.ReferencedTable
     , b.ReferencedKey
FROM pg_constraint AS pg
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
    ( SELECT '(' || string_agg(conrelid::regclass || '.' || fkey, ',' ORDER BY fkey.ORDINALITY) || ')' AS ReferencingKey
        FROM pg_get_constraintdef(pg.oid) AS fk
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL string_to_table(translate(regexp_substr(fk, '\([^\)]*\)', 1, 1), '() ', ''), ',') WITH ORDINALITY AS fkey
    ) AS a
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
    ( SELECT '(' || string_agg(ReferencedTable || '.' || rkey, ',' ORDER BY rkey.ORDINALITY) || ')' AS ReferencedKey
           , ReferencedTable
        FROM pg_get_constraintdef(pg.oid) AS fk
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL split_part((regexp_match(fk, 'REFERENCES\s\w+'))[1], ' ', 2) AS ReferencedTable
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL string_to_table(translate(regexp_substr(fk, '\([^\)]*\)', 1, 2), '() ', ''), ',') WITH ORDINALITY AS rkey
       GROUP BY ReferencedTable
    ) AS b
WHERE  contype = 'f'
  AND connamespace = 'public' ::regnamespace
```

Result :

| referencingtable | referencingkey | referencedtable | referencedkey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test2 | (test2.id2,test2.seq2) | test1 | (test1.id1,test1.seq1) |

Creating a plpgsql function with `schema_name` as input data and with a dynamic query :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(IN schema_name text, OUT Referencing_Table text, OUT Referencing_Key text, OUT Referenced_Table text)
  RETURNS setof record LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
DECLARE
  _row record ;
BEGIN

FOR _row IN
( SELECT conrelid::regclass AS ReferencingTable
     , a.ReferencingKey
     , b.ReferencedTable
     , b.ReferencedKey
FROM pg_constraint AS pg
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
    ( SELECT '(' || string_agg(conrelid::regclass || '.' || fkey, ',' ORDER BY fkey.ORDINALITY) || ')' AS ReferencingKey
        FROM pg_get_constraintdef(pg.oid) AS fk
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL string_to_table(translate(regexp_substr(fk, '\([^\)]*\)', 1, 1), '() ', ''), ',') WITH ORDINALITY AS fkey
    ) AS a
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
    ( SELECT '(' || string_agg(ReferencedTable || '.' || rkey, ',' ORDER BY rkey.ORDINALITY) || ')' AS ReferencedKey
           , ReferencedTable
        FROM pg_get_constraintdef(pg.oid) AS fk
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL split_part((regexp_match(fk, 'REFERENCES\s\w+'))[1], ' ', 2) AS ReferencedTable
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL string_to_table(translate(regexp_substr(fk, '\([^\)]*\)', 1, 2), '() ', ''), ',') WITH ORDINALITY AS rkey
       GROUP BY ReferencedTable
    ) AS b
WHERE contype = 'f'
  AND connamespace = schema_name ::regnamespace )
LOOP
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE FORMAT (
  'SELECT %L :: text AS Referencing_Table, %s :: text AS Referencing_Key, %L :: text AS Referenced_Table
     FROM %I LEFT JOIN %I ON %s = %s
    WHERE %s IS NULL'
  , _row.ReferencingTable
  , _row.ReferencingKey
  , _row.ReferencedTable
  , _row.ReferencingTable
  , _row.ReferencedTable
  , _row.ReferencedKey
  , _row.ReferencingKey
  , _row.ReferencedKey
  ) ;
END LOOP ;
END ;
$$ ;
```

`SELECT * FROM test('public')` should return the list of foreign keys of any table `Referencing_Table` in schema `schema_name` with no correspondance in table `Referenced_Table`

but not able to test the result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6sBI6gbn) because not able to break the foreign key (superuser privilege)

Comment: This solution is not how we solved the issue (see my edit above), but it bears similarities to our solution, so I am going to mark it as the answer.